# Export docker registry credentials from Windows/WSL

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm doing a couple of experiments for a Kubernetes-based local dev environment and for that I'm exporting my local Docker registry credentials like this:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic -n default regcred \
     --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/home/user/.docker/config.json \
     --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

This works fine for me (Linux without a desktop environment), but fails for my colleagues using any sort of credentials store, in particular those on Windows/WSL2. Their `.docker/config.json` files do not contain credentials, but instead a reference to `credStore` called `desktop.exe`, which I can only assume to be "Docker Desktop".

Is there a way I could extract credentials from the Windows credential store (mostly) automatically? It's of course OK to make the person executing the script confirm credential store access, but the remainder of the process should ideally be automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it hasn't been all that difficult. I've written a Bash script (also requires `jq`) which extracts credentials from the credentials store and combines them with the original `.docker/config.json`.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ue

CREDHELPER=$(jq -r .credsStore < "${HOME}/.docker/config.json" )

STR=.

if [[ -n "$CREDHELPER" && "$CREDHELPER" != "null" ]]; then
    CRED_BINARY=docker-credential-$CREDHELPER

    REGS=$($CRED_BINARY list | jq -r 'keys | join(" ")' )
    for REG in $REGS; do
        CRED=$(echo $REG | $CRED_BINARY get | jq -rj '"\(.Username):\(.Secret)"' | base64 -w 0)
        STR="$STR * { \"auths\": { \"$REG\": { \"auth\": \"$CRED\" }}}"
    done
fi

jq -r "$STR" "${HOME}/.docker/config.json"
```